# CSS on hover direction

Tags: css

I need some help!

I have a div element, that needs an interaction on hover. See below:

```
div {

    width:298px;
    height: 62px;
    position:relative;  
}

div:hover{
    height:90px;
    }
```

However, it works but it hovers "downwards" I want this to do the opposite and go upwards how can I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `top` property to shift the element up by `20px`:

```
div:hover {
    top: -20px;
}
```